# Accessing OCaml minor GC info in a tight loop

Tags: performance, garbage-collection, ocaml, ffi

How can I quickly get the 
number of minor collections? I tried this ...

```
let get_minor_collection_count () =
  let stat = Gc.quick_stat ()
  in stat.minor_collections
```

... but the X64 assembly code emitted by `ocamlopt` version `4.07.1` looks like this:

```
_camlDemouser2__get_minor_collection_count_2666:
    subq    $8, %rsp
    movq    $1, %rdi
    movq    _caml_gc_quick_stat@GOTPCREL(%rip), %rax
    call    _caml_c_call
    movq    _caml_young_ptr@GOTPCREL(%rip), %r11
    movq    (%r11), %r15
    movq    24(%rax), %rax
    addq    $8, %rsp
    ret
```

If I use C code for accessing `caml_stat_minor_collections`, the access *itself* is fast<sup>1</sup>, but having to use `_caml_c_call` incurs relatively high costs for tiny C functions like this.

What can I do to remedy the situation?

1. Hope some future ocaml version adds something like `Gc.get_minor_free` (added with `4.03.0`), which is a similar tiny function for GC hacker wannabes like me :)
2. Or should I dig into the internal IL that `ocamlopt` uses?
3. Or could `flambda` help me? RTFM answers are ok :)

Thank you in advance for ideas / suggestions / code snippets!

---

<sup>**1:** `clang` emits `movq _caml_stat_minor_collections@GOTPCREL(%rip), %rax`.</sup>

Comment: Flambda would probably be able to help you.

Comment: @PatJ. Got one (or more) good links for me except for the Ocaml manual and realworldcaml? why put em plus some te t in an answer?

Comment: I don't really have more to say. What exactly are you trying to achieve?